# How to replace a value in a pandas dataframe with column name based on a condition?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks something like this:

[image]

I want to replace all 1's in the range A:D with the name of the column, so that the final result should resemble:

[image]

How can I do that?

You can recreate my dataframe with this:

```
dfz = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [1,0,0,1,0,0],
                    'B' : [1,0,0,1,0,1],
                    'C' : [1,0,0,1,3,1],
                    'D' : [1,0,0,1,0,0],
                    'E' : [22.0,15.0,None,10.,None,557.0]})
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

One way could be to use [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) and pass in a Series mapping column labels to values (those same labels in this case):

```
>>> dfz.loc[:, 'A':'D'].replace(1, pd.Series(dfz.columns, dfz.columns))
   A  B  C  D
0  A  B  C  D
1  0  0  0  0
2  0  0  0  0
3  A  B  C  D
4  0  0  3  0
5  0  B  C  0
```

To make the change permanent, you'd assign the returned DataFrame back to `dfz.loc[:, 'A':'D']`.

Solutions aside, it's useful to keep in mind that you may lose a lot of performance benefits when you mix numeric and string types in columns, as pandas is forced to use the generic 'object' dtype to hold the values.

Answer (score 10):

A solution using `where`:

```
>>> dfz.where(dfz != 1, dfz.columns.to_series(), axis=1)
   A  B  C  D      E
0  A  B  C  D   22.0
1  0  0  0  0   15.0
2  0  0  0  0    NaN
3  A  B  C  D   10.0
4  0  0  3  0    NaN
5  0  B  C  0  557.0
```

Comment: It is so short! How does it work? Could someone give an explanation?

Comment: `x.where(cond, y)`, with x/cond/y all of the same shape, returns a version of x with values at positions indicated by cond replaced with values taken from y. `axis=1` lets you supply a one-dimensional y and have ´where´ apply it row-by-row.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe it's not so elegant but...just looping through columns and replace:

```
for i in dfz[['A','B','C','D']].columns:
    dfz[i].replace(1,i,inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

I do prefer very elegant solution from @ajcr.

In case if you have column names that you cant use that easily for slicing, here is my solution:

```
dfz.ix[:, dfz.filter(regex=r'(A|B|C|D)').columns.tolist()] = (
    dfz[dfz!=1].ix[:,dfz.filter(regex=r'(A|B|C|D)').columns.tolist()]
               .apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.name))
)
```

Output:

```
In [207]: dfz
Out[207]:
   A  B  C  D      E
0  A  B  C  D   22.0
1  0  0  0  0   15.0
2  0  0  0  0    NaN
3  A  B  C  D   10.0
4  0  0  3  0    NaN
5  0  B  C  0  557.0
```