# How to iterate over rows in a DataFrame in Pandas and convert it to list?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame that looks like that

```
ID  A   B  C  E  X
M1  1   1  1  0  0
M2  1   1  0  0  0
M3  1   0  0  1  1
M4  1   1  0  1  0
M5  0   1  1  0  0
```

and I'm trying to convert to a list that looks like

```
M1  A  B  C  0  0
M2  A  B  0  0  0
M3  A  0  0  E  X
M4  A  B  0  E  0
M5  0  B  C  0  0
```

Is it possible to do that in pandas?

Comment: probably Duplicate of this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37032043/how-to-replace-a-value-in-a-pandas-dataframe-with-column-name-based-on-a-conditi

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way

```
In [411]: dff = df.set_index('ID')

In [412]: (dff * dff.columns).replace('', 0)
Out[412]:
    A  B  C  E  X
ID
M1  A  B  C  0  0
M2  A  B  0  0  0
M3  A  0  0  E  X
M4  A  B  0  E  0
M5  0  B  C  0  0
```