# I want to replace values of dataframe as a column name in python. How am I suppose to do that?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to convert following values using loop.

```
        {'Id':2, 'A':"no", 'B':"no", 'C':"no", 'D':"yes"},
        {'Id':3, 'A':"yes", 'B':"yes", 'C':"yes", 'D':"no"},
        {'Id':4, 'A':"yes", 'B':"no", 'C':"yes", 'D':"no"},
        {'Id':5, 'A':"no", 'B':"yes", 'C':"no", 'D':"yes"}]
```

https://ibb.co/7NL69BY (link to dataframe)

I have used 'map' for indivisual rows. But I want to loop it.

```
df['B'] = df['B'].map({"yes": "B", "no": "-"})
df['C'] = df['C'].map({"yes": "C", "no": "-"})
df['D'] = df['D'].map({"yes": "D", "no": "-"})
```

(Link to result)https://ibb.co/JsJjqZr
Help me to use loop please.

Comment: `for col in 'BCD': df[col] = df[col].map({'yes':col, 'no':'-'});` replace `'BCD'` with `list(columns)`.

Comment: @ Heramb Lonkar, please see the answer if that's useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this..

this is borrowed from the [linked post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37032043/how-to-replace-a-value-in-a-pandas-dataframe-with-column-name-based-on-a-conditi)

### Example DataFrame:

```
>>> df
      A    B    C    D
Id
2    no   no   no  yes
3   yes  yes  yes   no
4   yes   no  yes   no
5    no  yes   no  yes
```

### Solution:

```
>>> df.loc[:, 'A':'D'].replace('yes', pd.Series(df.columns, df.columns)).replace('no', '-')
    A  B  C  D
Id
2   -  -  -  D
3   A  B  C  -
4   A  -  C  -
5   -  B  -  D
```

Another solution as @– Quang Hoang mentioned..

```
>>> for col in 'ABCD':
...   df[col] = df[col].map({'yes':col, 'no':'-'})
...
>>> df
    A  B  C  D
Id
2   -  -  -  D
3   A  B  C  -
4   A  -  C  -
5   -  B  -  D
```

OR

```
>>> for cell in df[['A','B','C','D']].columns:
...     df[cell].replace({'yes':col, 'no':'-'}, inplace=True)
...
>>> df
    A  B  C  D
Id
2   -  -  -  D
3   D  D  D  -
4   D  -  D  -
5   -  D  -  D
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this solution:

```
import pandas as pd
x = pd.DataFrame([{'Id':2, 'A':"no", 'B':"no", 'C':"no", 'D':"yes"}, 
           {'Id':3, 'A':"yes", 'B':"yes", 'C':"yes", 'D':"no"}, 
           {'Id':4, 'A':"yes", 'B':"no", 'C':"yes", 'D':"no"}, 
           {'Id':5, 'A':"no", 'B':"yes", 'C':"no", 'D':"yes"}])  
x.set_index('Id')
headers = x.columns.to_list()
for col in headers:
    x[col] = x[col].map({"yes":col, "no":"-"})
```