# How to use lambda python function to use map as following?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to convert following code to lambda expression-

```
for i in col_headers:
    df_temp[i] = df[i].map({"yes":i, "no":"-"})
```

I tried with following code but I failed.

```
df_temp = df[].map({"yes":(lambda x: x, df.columns.to_list()), "no":"-"} )
```

Here is the smaple data and output.

```
data = ({'Id':[1,2,3,4,5],
        'A':['yes', 'no', 'yes', 'yes', 'no'],
        'B':['yes', 'no', 'yes', 'no', 'yes'],
        'C':['no', 'no', 'yes', 'yes', 'no'],
        'D':['no', 'yes', 'no', 'no', 'yes']})

df = pd.DataFrame(data = data)
df.set_index(["Id"], inplace = True, drop = True) 

for i in df.columns.to_list():
    df_temp[i] = df[i].map({"yes":i, "no":"-"}) 
df_temp
```

df_temp is the output I want but using lambda function.

Can you also explain me where did my logic go wrong?

Comment: Why is the `lambda` so necessary? This could be done with `df.mask(df.eq('yes')).fillna({x:x for x in df.columns}).replace({'no': '-'})`. Though I see nothing wrong with the simple loop; it's concise and fast.

Comment: `cond=df.eq('yes')` ; `pd.DataFrame(np.where(cond,df.columns.values[cond.mul(range(len(df.columns)))],'-'),
            columns=df.columns)` <- this is anothey way, but yes why is lambda so important

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I want to replace values of dataframe as a column name in python. How am I suppose to do that?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57872122/i-want-to-replace-values-of-dataframe-as-a-column-name-in-python-how-am-i-suppo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lambda with apply whitout for loop:

```
df.apply(lambda x: np.where(x.apply(lambda x: '-'  if x=='no' else x)==x,x.name,x.apply(lambda x: '-'  if x=='no' else x)))
```

Output:

```
df
    A  B  C  D
Id            
1   A  B  -  -
2   -  -  -  D
3   A  B  C  -
4   A  -  C  -
5   -  B  -  D
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to use copy method to create a copy of the data frame.

```
df_temp = df.copy()
```

Then,

```
for i in df.columns.to_list():
    df_temp[i] = df[i].map(lambda x: i if x=='yes' else '-')
df_temp
```

The result is:

```
    A  B  C  D
Id            
1   A  B  -  -
2   -  -  -  D
3   A  B  C  -
4   A  -  C  -
5   -  B  -  D
```

Note that the **map** method is for **Series** not for **DataFrame**. So you need to use for loop whether using dictionary or lambda function.

Anyway there are many easier ways to do your job.